# pChartで作ったグラフで日本語が表示できない

Tags: php

pChartで日本語を含むグラフを作成したいですが、タイトルが文字化けしてしまい読めないです。

**LAMP環境**

- VirtualBox 5.0.6
- CentOS 6.5
- PHP 5.3
- Apache 2.2
- MySQL 5.1
- pChart 2.14

php.iniで下記を設定をしました。

```
;mbstring.internal_encoding = EUC-JP → mbstring.internal_encoding = UTF-8
;mbstring.language = Japanese → mbstring.language = Japanese
;mbstring.http_input = auto → mbstring.http_input = auto
;mbstring.detect_order = auto → mbstring.detect_order = auto
```

**test.php**

```
<?php 

include("class/pData.class.php");
include("class/pDraw.class.php");
include("class/pImage.class.php");

$myData = new pData();
$myData->addPoints(array(12,11,32,4,90,48),"Serie1");
$myData->setSerieDescription("Serie1","Aさん");
$myData->setSerieOnAxis("Serie1",0);

$myData->addPoints(array(22,60,3,0,15,22),"Serie2");
$myData->setSerieDescription("Serie2","Bさん");
$myData->setSerieOnAxis("Serie2",0);

$myData->addPoints(array("1月","2月","3月","4月","5月","6月"),"Absissa");
$myData->setAbscissa("Absissa");

$myData->setAxisPosition(0,AXIS_POSITION_LEFT);
$myData->setAxisName(0,"1st axis");
$myData->setAxisUnit(0,"");

$myPicture = new pImage(500,230,$myData);
$Settings = array("R"=>170, "G"=>183, "B"=>87, "Dash"=>1, "DashR"=>190, "DashG"=>203, "DashB"=>107);
$myPicture->drawFilledRectangle(0,0,500,230,$Settings);

$Settings = array("StartR"=>219, "StartG"=>231, "StartB"=>139, "EndR"=>1, "EndG"=>138, "EndB"=>68, "Alpha"=>50);
$myPicture->drawGradientArea(0,0,500,230,DIRECTION_VERTICAL,$Settings);

$myPicture->drawRectangle(0,0,499,229,array("R"=>0,"G"=>0,"B"=>0));

$myPicture->setShadow(TRUE,array("X"=>1,"Y"=>1,"R"=>50,"G"=>50,"B"=>50,"Alpha"=>20));

$myPicture->setFontProperties(array("FontName"=>"fonts/sazanami-gothic.ttf","FontSize"=>14));
$TextSettings = array("Align"=>TEXT_ALIGN_MIDDLEMIDDLE , "R"=>255, "G"=>255, "B"=>255);
$myPicture->drawText(250,25,"販売実績",$TextSettings);

$myPicture->setShadow(FALSE);
$myPicture->setGraphArea(50,50,475,190);
$myPicture->setFontProperties(array("R"=>0,"G"=>0,"B"=>0,"FontName"=>"fonts/sazanami-gothic.ttf","FontSize"=>8));

$Settings = array("Pos"=>SCALE_POS_LEFTRIGHT , "Mode"=>SCALE_MODE_ADDALL_START0 , "LabelingMethod"=>LABELING_DIFFERENT , "GridR"=>255, "GridG"=>255, "GridB"=>255, "GridAlpha"=>20, "TickR"=>0, "TickG"=>0, "TickB"=>0, "TickAlpha"=>50, "LabelRotation"=>0, "CycleBackground"=>1, "DrawXLines"=>1, "DrawSubTicks"=>1, "SubTickR"=>255, "SubTickG"=>0, "SubTickB"=>0, "SubTickAlpha"=>50, "DrawYLines"=>ALL);
$myPicture->drawScale($Settings);

$myPicture->setShadow(TRUE,array("X"=>1,"Y"=>1,"R"=>50,"G"=>50,"B"=>50,"Alpha"=>10));

$Config = array("DisplayValues"=>1, "Gradient"=>1, "AroundZero"=>1);
$myPicture->drawBarChart($Config);

$Config = array("FontR"=>0, "FontG"=>0, "FontB"=>0, "FontName"=>"fonts/sazanami-gothic.ttf", "FontSize"=>8, "Margin"=>6, "Alpha"=>30, "BoxSize"=>5, "Style"=>LEGEND_ROUND , "Mode"=>LEGEND_VERTICAL );
$myPicture->drawLegend(50,15,$Config);

$myPicture->stroke(); 
?>
```

TeraPad で test.php を編集しています。文字コードを SHIFT-JIS にして保存・実行すると、グラフが表示できますが、日本語は文字化けします。
文字コードを UTF(UTF-8N) にして保存・実行すると、グラフが表示できません。

どのようにすれば、日本語のグラフが表示できますか？

ご教示よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: こちらの環境(Ubuntu 15.04, php 5.6.4, pChart 2.1.4)では問題なく表示できています。可能であればコード全体を示していただくと何か分かるかもしれません。

Comment: 有難うございます。VM環境でサンプルを利用して試しています。確認をよろしくお願いします。

Comment: nice さんのコードを試してみたのですが、日本語がきちんと表示されています。こちらで変更したのは `"FontName"=>"fonts/sazanami-gothic.ttf"` の部分のフォントパスを絶対パスにしただけです。

Comment: 絶対パス"FontName"=>"/var/www/html/Chart/fonts/sazanami-gothic.ttf"に変更しましたが、特に変わらないみたいです。
sazanami-gothic.ttfをfontsディレクトリに入れてから、なにか再起動は必要ですか？ UTF(UTF-8N) にして保存する必要ですね。

Comment: 再起動の必要はないです。うーん、何が原因なのでしょうか…。また気付いた事がありましたらコメントします。

Comment: UTF(UTF-8N) にして保存したものを実行すれば、
「 HTTP 500  Web サイトはページを表示できません」のメッセージが表示されます。
原因が分かりましたら、教えて下さい。

Comment: コマンドラインで `php test.php > test.png` を実行してみて下さい。おそらく、なんらかのエラーメッセージが表示されると思います。

Comment: 仮想端末でphp test.php > test.pngを実行しました。SHIFT-JISやUTF(UTF-8N)で保存しても、エラーが表示されませんでした。
http:// xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/Chart/test.phpなら、 UTF(UTF-8N) で保存したときに、エラーが発生します。

Comment: ちなみに、test.png の中身はどうなっていますでしょうか？

Comment: あ、今気が付きましたが、`http://.../Chart/test.php` としているのですね。そうしますと、画像データを直接ブラウザ側へ送信しているわけですね。。。

Comment: php test.php > test.pngの実行結果
UTF(UTF-8N) で保存したとき、test.png の中身は空でした。
SHIFT-JISで保存したとき、test.png の中身は日本語文字化けのグラフでした。

Comment: 念の為確認ですが、UTF-8 で保存した test.php の一行目は `<?php` となっていますでしょうか？

Comment: UTF-8 で保存した test.php の一行目は <?php >となっていません。
UTF-8N で保存した test.php の一行目は <?php >となっています。
両方とも日本語化けしています。

Comment: test.php の一行目が `<?php` になっていないと PHP スクリプトとして実行されないので(エラーメッセージは表示されない)、それが原因かもしれないと思ったのですが、違った様ですね。。

Comment: EmEditorでtest.phpを編集してUTF-8 (BOMなし)で保存して
php test.php > test.pngの実行結果は下記エラーがたくさん表示されました。
PHP Warning:  imagettftext(): Could not find/open font in /var/www/html/Chart/cl                                          ass/pDraw.class.php on line 1023
PHP Warning:  imagettfbbox(): Could not find/open font in /var/www/html/Chart/cl                                          ass/pImage.class.php on line 211
解決方法を教えていただけますか？

Comment: `/var/www/html/Chart/fonts/sazanami-gothic.ttf` は存在しますか？ 存在する場合はパーミッションを確認してみて下さい(読み込み可能かどうか)。

Comment: /var/www/html/Chart/fonts/sazanami-gothic.ttf は存在します。
パーミッションは644になっていますから、
他のｔｔｆのパーミッションと同じように666に変えたら、
日本語をちゃんと表示できるようになりました。
本当にありがとうございます。助かりました。

Answer (score 1):

コメント欄でのアドバイスを元に、フォントファイル周りを確認してみました。

`/var/www/html/Chart/fonts/sazanami-gothic.ttf` は存在していますが、パーミッションが `644` になっていたので、他のttfファイルのパーミッションと同じように `666` に変えたら、日本語がちゃんと表示できるようになりました。

---

*この投稿は [@nice さんのコメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/18303/pchart%e3%81%a7%e4%bd%9c%e3%81%a3%e3%81%9f%e3%82%b0%e3%83%a9%e3%83%95%e3%81%af%e6%97%a5%e6%9c%ac%e8%aa%9e%e3%81%8c%e8%a1%a8%e7%a4%ba%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment16960_18303) の内容を元に コミュニティwiki として投稿しました。*